# How to do System Dynamics simulations / diagrams in Mathematica?

Tags: animation, simulation, modeling, system-modeler, system-modeling

[System Dynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_dynamics) is an approach to understanding the behaviour of complex systems over time. It deals with internal feedback loops and time delays that affect the behaviour of the entire system.  What makes using system dynamics different from other approaches to studying complex systems is the use of feedback loops and stocks and flows. These elements help describe how even seemingly simple systems display **baffling nonlinearity**

Here is how a system diagram looks like:

[image]

Apperently I should be able to this with [System Modeler](http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/) by loading [this modelica library](https://www.modelica.org/libraries/SystemDynamics) but I am also told [here](http://www.simulistics.com/blog/system-dynamics-modelling-modelica-modelling-language) that:

> The downside, as I understand it, is that **each different use of a
>   System Dynamics symbol requires its own entry in the library**. For
>   example, a stock with one inflow and one outflow requires a different
>   Modelica symbol from one with one inflow and 2 outflows. Also (again,
>   as I understand it), every separate equation requires its own symbol
>   to be defined and added to the library before it can be used.

¿Anyone here can confirm or deny this? ¿Is this a limitation inherent in all **Modelica** enviroments?  ¿or it is an implementation limitation on this particular library?

and, going back to the original aim of this question: Is there a less expensive way (than System Modeler) to do this **in Mathematica, *without* System Modeler**?

Comment: I am surprised that there is no tags for: "simulation" and "nonlinearity"

Comment: Check http://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/features/

Comment: I was kind of hoping someone here had first had experience with System Modeler

Comment: I found this: https://www.modelica.org/libraries/SystemDynamics, apparently since  System Modeler uses the Modelica language it should be able to use it.

Comment: Please edit your question by adding your comments. They provide useful context info for the wannabe answerers.

Comment: Editing my question...

Comment: This is really a SystemModeler question, this [this discussion whether these questions should be on-topic](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/413/are-questions-related-to-systemmodeler-on-topic) became relevant for the first time.  After having looked at the trial version of SystemModeler, I'd say they shouldn't.  SystemModeler seems to be a completely separate product which happens to have an interface to Mma. Perhaps rephrasing the question to be Mathematica-focused would be appropriate.

Comment: I wrote a new answer on that meta thread: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/542/12  I think that if your question is about doing these simulations in SystemModeler / Modelica, that's off topic.  If it's about doing it in Mathematica, it's on topic, but SystemModeler might be a better tool for the task ...

Comment: My main interest is to model system dynamics in mathematica, I only added  System Modeler to the questions because it seems related, but since I own Mathematica (and I do not own System Modeler) I am way more interested in being able to do this in Mathematica that on System Modeler

Comment: If you like me wanted to play with System Modeler as a hobbist: http://store.wolfram.com/view/app/systemmodelerhe/ System Modeler **Home Edition**!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The limitation you quote is not a general limitation of Modelica. It is possible to define a Modelica component that has a variable number of inputs/outputs. Typically the number of inputs/outputs is then given by a parameter to that component.

For example, the following component has one input but 2 outputs, varied with the parameter `nout`:

```
model SIMO "Single input, multiple output"
  parameter Integer nout=2 "Number of outputs";
  RealInput u "Connector of Real input signal";
  RealOutput y[nout] "Connector of Real output signals";
equation
  {{{your equations}}}
end SIMO;
```

I have not used the System Dynamics modelica library, so cannot speak to how they have chosen to implement their interfaces.

It would be fully possible to create your custom models in Mathematica by defining equations from the ground up, and then simulating them using for example `NDSolve`. This would however require a significant amount of manual labor.

If you want to stay in the Wolfram product universe, SystemModeler would be the way to go. It allows you to simulate and interact with models from Mathematica, using a Mathematica package bundled with the product.

An overview of features of the Mathematica package, called `WSMLink`, can be found at http://wolfram.com/system-modeler/features/analysis-mathematica.html.

Documentation to see how the package actually is used is found at http://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/WSMLink/guide/WSMLink.html.

---

Update:

The SystemDynamics library mentioned in the original question is now available for download in a version compatible with Wolfram SystemModeler at the bottom of this blog post: http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/06/11/energy-resource-dynamics-with-the-new-system-dynamics-library-for-systemmodeler/

Comment: And... is there a way to achieve the same _without_ System Modeler?

Comment: Certainly possible, but not easy. NDSolve is powerful for solving differential equations, but Mathematica currently does not have an easy way to graphically build dynamic systems. It is of course possible to create "components" (Symbol structures with equations and graphical representations) and build functionality to connect them together, and then using NDSolve to simulate the system, and the Graphics functionality to build up the system diagram. This would be a massive undertaking though.

Comment: And what about the part " Also (again, as I understand it), **every separate equation requires its own symbol** to be defined and added to the library before it can be used." Is that true?

Comment: No, that is not true. A class (model or component) in Modelica (and therefore SystemModeler) can contain any number of equations, without defining separate classes for each equation. Of course, if you want to reuse an equation or a collection of equations, for example for the behavior of stock, you can create a class with those equations, and use that class as a component in your bigger model.

Answer (score 4):

One possible alternative might be *Control Systems* in Mathematica.

With Control Systems you can carry out analysis, design, and simulation of time control systems.

For an example here an automated house heating system controlled by a thermostat. 
(Sorry. I really tried to use the drawing tools for a nifty graphic, but...alas...i'm not even able to draw a simple house, so I count on your imagination)

Here I show how to analyze the controller and its performance in a closed loop:

```
system = TransferFunctionModel[(0.5/((0.2 s + 1) (2 s + 1))), s];

pid = pid = PIDTune[system, Automatic, "PIDData"];

cloop = pid["ReferenceOutput"];

or = OutputResponse[cloop, UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 4}];

p = Plot[%, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "y"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[15], 
  PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

Using a PID controller instead reduces the bump a little bit:

```
pid = pid = PIDTune[system, "PID", "PIDData"];
```

[image]

On Woflram blog in '11 Andrew Moylan wrote two very exciting and amusing posts on stabilising an inverted pendulum (segeway) using Control Systems and with decent animations. (http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/01/19/stabilized-inverted-pendulum/)

Hope that this was informative for you. I know that this is not at all visual modeling, but the principles are the same.

Comment: Any book, website or guide you recommend on how to take a systemdynamics "graphic model" and translate it into something that can be fed in to TransferFunctionModel?

Comment: Maybe you could please answer this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22798/how-do-i-represent-a-system-dynamics-feedback-loop using this TransferFunctionModel?

Comment: Very interesting answer. Would the Control Systems Framework be able to handle vector equations and could something like `WhenEvent` be included as in the `NDSolve` framework? (e.g. what are the downsides of control systems framework as compared to NDSolve)

Answer (score 3):

## Using Modelica for System Dynamics

The way to go for doing System Dynamics (i.e. continuous time, equation based simulations describing the changes of a system's states by flows—essentially reducing a system of higher order ODEs to a system of first-order ODE) within the Wolfram universe is to turn to System Modeler which is built upon [Modelica](https://modelica.org/modelicalanguage)—a simulation language for cyber-physical systems—as Malte has mentioned in his answer.

### Downsides of the System Dynamics library

Unfortunately, some of the "downsides" mentioned do indeed apply to the before mentioned [System Dynamics library](https://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/libraries/system-dynamics/), which is purely build using *information or signal flows* as I have explained in [this tallk](https://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/libraries/system-dynamics/)(→ minutes 06:28 to 10:00) at the Wolfram Technology Conference 2020. This forfeits a lot of Modelica's powerful features. To give an example, modeling a *mass outflow* from a stock as an *information input*, as it is done in that library, means that we cannot leave that connector unconnected in case there is no outflow from the stock. So we will need a special class for a stock having no outflow which is rather cumbersome—a reason why the library is rather unheard of within the system dynamics community.

### A new Modelica library for System Dynamics

A lot of the flexibility of Modelica is tied to the use of *acausal connectors* for physical connections (e.g. the mass flows in System Dyanmics). There is now a new, free library available in the System Modeler Libaray Store: [Business Simulation Library (BSL)](https://www.wolfram.com/system-modeler/libraries/business-simulation/). It makes use of acausal connectors in implementing System Dynamics and offers a lot of the convenience known from dedicated SD tools.

The example of a process of social diffusion given in the OP (e.g. the bass diffusion model of new product adoption) is included as an example in the library, which models the closely related process of epidemic spread in a SIR model:

[image: SIR Model Diagram]

As you can see, the process of diffusion is modeled as a compact component `Diffusion` (e.g. *becoming_infected*). You can see how it is implemented in the [documentation](https://bsl-support.de/BusinessSimulation/BusinessSimulation.MoleculesOfStructure.Actuators.Diffusion.html).

Comment: Great work, Guido!

Answer (score 2):

There is an open-source Modelica system called OpenModelica at www.openmodelica.org.

Frankly, I am a little baffled at what you are calling a "downside".  Modelica is an object oriented language, so only different *classes* need to be defined within the library.  A single class can be implemented as many *objects* within your model.  For example, a resistor class need only be defined once, but you may have several resistors with different values within your model.  I would think that it should be expected that a component governed by a different set of constitutive equations would require a new class.  What would you propose as an alternative?